# jQuery post method to send input file to PHP on change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As I understood $.ajax() is equivalent to $.post(). I am trying to use $.post to submit input file to PHP script. The purpose is to upload the image once the user browse and choose it.

I am trying to use something simple like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:file").change(function(){
$("#fileName").data($(this).val());
$.post( "upload.php", { fileName: $(this).val() }, function( data ) {
$( ".div1" ).html( data );
}); 
}); 
});
```

When I echo `$_POST["fileName"]` it shows:

> C:\fakepath\imag-name.jpg

When I try to get the file data using `basename($_FILES["fileName"]["name"])`
I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: fileName ...... etc

Any advice or solution is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse things from Javascript to PHP, one is server side one is client side.

**Learn more here:**  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

The simplest solution is make a browser cookie in JS and retrieve it in PHP.
The value would be the URL of the uploaded image, probably best to give these cookies a programatically generated name (Out of scope of question.

Comment: Please click the tick next to my answer if this helps you in the least. if you cannot figure this out I can go into further details just comment and let me know. :)

Comment: What's he asking for is certainly possible.